# Googlesearch doesn't iterate over list

Tags: python, google-search

I'm currently trying to search multiple list queries with googlesearch in python. Despite syntax being ok, the results are only the 30 ones of the first query itself meaning that the for syntax isn't iterating.

Do you know what could be happening? I know it must be something I'm missing but since no error is generated, I'm having a hard time knowing why doesn't iterate :/

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from googlesearch import search

queries = ["plan nacional fiat","plan nacional peugeot","plan nacional citroen","plan nacional jeep","plan gobierno fiat","plan gobierno peugeot","plan gobierno citroen",
         "plan gobierno jeep","plan de ahorro fiat","plan de ahorro peugeot","plan de ahorro citroen","plan de ahorro jeep","fiat financiacion","peugeot financiacion",
         "citroen financiacion","jeep financiacion","asesor fiat","asesor citroen","asesor peugeot","asesor jeep","plan caido fiat","plan caido peugeot","plan caido citroen","plan caido jeep"]
data_append=[]
 
for query in queries:
    data_append.append(search(query, tld="com.ar", num=30, stop=1, pause=2))

df = pd.DataFrame({'URLs':data_append[0]})

df.to_excel('data.xlsx', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: `data_append[0]` takes just the first element, is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Is bringing the first column of the appended df, which in this case is the only column so its redundant. Problem is that the iterator doesn't iterate, it just takes the first iteration and thats all

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](//developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](//policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries. Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches from your IP address.

Comment: Ohhh that's why, great to know! Thanks!